# Что даёт %I 38400 для переменной окружения TERM?

Tags: linux, bash, systemd, login

Искал, как настроить автологин на нужный TTY. Нашёл. Там используется `/sbin/agetty` через сервис systemd. Так вот, там такая запись:

> ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin username --noclear **%I 38400 linux**

В общем, то что жирным выделено уходит в переменную окружения TERM. Нужно только понять, что это даёт. Гуглинг что-то не помог мне.

Я вообще ни разу ниигде не находил, чтобы было описание того, что и как должно быть записано в стандартные переменные окружения. Типа `man TERM`, может есть какие-то ресурсы, где можно посмотреть?

Comment: `man agetty` baud_rate

Comment: @vp_arth, да вроде для них там другой синтаксис

Comment: видимо `38400` - это боды, а `%I` - что-то еще

Comment: первый параметр программы agetty — это имя порта. приведённый же вами фрагмент свидетельствует о том, что это выдержка из [systemd template unit file](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin username --noclear **%I 38400 linux**

см. [`man agetty`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=agetty&category=8&russian=2):

- **%I** — это параметр, который `systemd` должен заменить на имя конкретного `tty` устройства для которого запускается `agetty`, обычно это `tty[0-6]`. Но можно запустить логин и, например, на последовательном порте (`ttyS0`, или `ttyUSB0`).
- **38400** — это «скорость» терминала в бодах, для виртуальных терминалов `/dev/tty*` это не имеет ни какого практического значения. Для «настоящего» терминала на последовательном интерфейсе это установит скорость последовательного порта.
- **linux** — это тип терминала, просто значение, в которое устанавливается переменная `TERM`.

Собственно само значение `TERM`,  как [говорит](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) POSIX используется «некоторыми программами» чтобы определить, какие дополнительные возможности терминала они могут задействовать. Вообще говоря, сам формат этого значения и его интерпретация остаются полностью на совести конкретных программ.

На практике, обычно, значение `TERM` — это имя терминала из базы [`terminfo`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo), а конкретно имя файла в `/usr/share/terminfo/*/*`. В нём в частности определяется, например, доступны ли на терминале цвета, сколько цветов, как именно вывести текст в определённом месте экрана и т.п. Обычно эти данные используют программы с псевдографическим интерфейсом, в частности, основанные на [`(n)curses`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=ncurses&category=3&russian=3).

В общем `TERM` — это одна из тех доисторических вещей, доставшихся в наследство с тех времён, когда компьютеры были большими, а «терминал» представлял из себя отдельное устройство, подключаемое через последовательный интерфейс. Выносить такие операции, как «вывести строчку в позицию (X,Y) экрана» на уровень драйвера не имело смысла, а каждый терминал реализовывал эту операцию по-своему, с помощью специальных управляющих команд, передаваемых в общем потоке данных. Сегодня, если не делаешь что-то необычное, например, подключаешь внешний терминал из 70—80-х годов XX века через последовательный порт, то это значение не должно представлять интереса.